# GetDC() or CClientDC dc(this) does not work in non-message function?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I'm trying to set background image in a MFC Dialog, I succeeded in getting the Client device context, while writing `CDC* pDC=GetDC()`, or `CClientDC dc(this)` , inside functions like `OnTimer`, `OnPaint`, `OnEraseBkgrd`, but not in a new declared function(also in `CDialog` class).

I tested this by a simple drawing function, like drawing a rectangle in both case, the result is that, if I write it in `OnTimer`, `OnPaint`, `OnEraseBkgrd`, it works well, but in my declared new function it doesn't !

Anyone can teach me how to get client dc in non-message functions?

Answer (score 0):

Why OnTimer handler for drawing?

You should use WM_PAINT (or in some cases WM_ERASEBKGND) message to do the drawing.
What is the new declared function?

All names you quoted are message handlers. Those functions are mapped to the message map and they are called by the framework when a message is received.

To set the background you should use WM_ERASEBKGND. The handler supplies device context you should use for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing to screen should only be done in OnPaint (or OnEraseBkgrd). If you need to prompt drawing from elsewhere in your dialog then you need to call InvalidateRect() which will subsequently call OnPaint(). When you OnPaint() is called, you can call pDC->GetClipBox() to get the rect which needs updating.

I think the best way to do what you want to do would be to store a pointer to the background image in your dialog class, then when you want to change the background image, set the bitmap pointer and call InvalidateRect(). Your OnPaint() function will then do the BitBlt to actually draw the new bitmap.